# Is Facebook.createApplication actually real?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, fbjs

Reading the Facebook [FBJS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/createApplication) documentation I found the method `Facebook.createApplication`. I'm trying to render FBJS in an iFrame application, and I can't seem to initialize the `Facebook` object. Further more, there's no documentation showing how to exactly initialize FBJS in an iFrame. My questions are as follows:

1. Is Facebook.createApplication deprecated?
2. Is it possible to render FBJS in an iFrame application?
3. If so, how does one initialize FBJS?

Answer (score 1):

1 yes
2 yes, but with limited functionality.
3 initialization and html doc type you need to use are documented in the javascript reference on facebook.

UPDATE:

Meanwhile the answer is NO. Automated creation of apps got disabled at all.

Comment: Gotta say I never found a way to make it work. A working example would be nice.

Comment: Meanwhile this has been disabled completely by Facebook.